# Skip backpropagation in CNN training for faster training in Caffe

Tags: deep-learning, conv-neural-network, caffe

My intention is to speed up training process using Weights from previous trained models to similar layers in new model training.

Say I have two models 1st model and 2nd model.

1st model is train from scratch.

2nd model has two additional layers `(conv_1_1 and relu_1_1)` difference from 1st model. The rest of layers are same.

So I like to back-propagate only those layers they are different layers from 1st model and those same layers as 1st model are not retrained. Then intention is to speed up training the 2nd model.

For that what I do is I set `lr_mult and decay_mult` to 0.

But found out that training time of 2nd model is still as long as that of 1st model.

I think they are still multiplying with 0, so even though weights are not updated, computation is still there.

How can I skip `backpropagation` at all in those same layers?

I checked log file and found as

```
I0830 13:40:26.546422 10580 net.cpp:226] mbox_loss needs backward computation.
I0830 13:40:26.546432 10580 net.cpp:228] mbox_priorbox does not need backward computation.
I0830 13:40:26.546437 10580 net.cpp:226] mbox_conf needs backward computation.
I0830 13:40:26.546440 10580 net.cpp:226] mbox_loc needs backward computation.
I0830 13:40:26.546444 10580 net.cpp:228] conv_6_norm_mbox_priorbox does not need backward computation.
I0830 13:40:26.546448 10580 net.cpp:226] conv_6_norm_mbox_conf_flat needs backward computation.
I0830 13:40:26.546452 10580 net.cpp:226] conv_6_norm_mbox_conf_perm needs backward computation.
I0830 13:40:26.546455 10580 net.cpp:226] conv_6_norm_mbox_conf needs backward computation.
I0830 13:40:26.546460 10580 net.cpp:226] conv_6_norm_mbox_loc_flat needs backward computation.
I0830 13:40:26.546464 10580 net.cpp:226] conv_6_norm_mbox_loc_perm needs backward computation.
I0830 13:40:26.546468 10580 net.cpp:226] conv_6_norm_mbox_loc needs backward computation.
I0830 13:40:26.546471 10580 net.cpp:226] conv_6_norm_conv_6_norm_0_split needs backward computation.
I0830 13:40:26.546475 10580 net.cpp:226] conv_6_norm needs backward computation.
I0830 13:40:26.546478 10580 net.cpp:226] relu_6 needs backward computation.
I0830 13:40:26.546481 10580 net.cpp:226] conv_6 needs backward computation.
I0830 13:40:26.546485 10580 net.cpp:226] pool_5 needs backward computation.
I0830 13:40:26.546489 10580 net.cpp:226] relu_5 needs backward computation.
I0830 13:40:26.546492 10580 net.cpp:226] conv_5 needs backward computation.
I0830 13:40:26.546495 10580 net.cpp:226] pool_4 needs backward computation.
I0830 13:40:26.546499 10580 net.cpp:226] relu_4 needs backward computation.
I0830 13:40:26.546502 10580 net.cpp:226] conv_4 needs backward computation.
I0830 13:40:26.546505 10580 net.cpp:226] pool_3 needs backward computation.
I0830 13:40:26.546509 10580 net.cpp:226] relu_3 needs backward computation.
I0830 13:40:26.546512 10580 net.cpp:226] conv_3 needs backward computation.
I0830 13:40:26.546515 10580 net.cpp:226] pool_2 needs backward computation.
I0830 13:40:26.546519 10580 net.cpp:226] relu_2 needs backward computation.
I0830 13:40:26.546522 10580 net.cpp:226] conv_2 needs backward computation.
I0830 13:40:26.546525 10580 net.cpp:226] pool_1 needs backward computation.
I0830 13:40:26.546530 10580 net.cpp:226] relu_1_1 needs backward computation.
I0830 13:40:26.546532 10580 net.cpp:226] conv_1_1 needs backward computation.
I0830 13:40:26.546536 10580 net.cpp:228] relu_1 does not need backward computation.
I0830 13:40:26.546540 10580 net.cpp:228] conv_1 does not need backward computation.
I0830 13:40:26.546545 10580 net.cpp:228] data_data_0_split does not need backward computation.
I0830 13:40:26.546548 10580 net.cpp:228] data does not need backward computation.
```

So only `conv_1 and relu_1` are not back propagated. But other layers are still back propagated.

How can I switch off back propagation in the following layers

```
conv_6_norm_conv_6_norm_0_split, conv_6_norm, relu_6, conv_6, pool_5, relu_5, conv_5, pool_4, relu_4, conv_4,pool_3, relu_3, conv_3, pool_2, relu_2, conv_2
```

Train.prototxt file is as follow.

```
name: "RegNet_train_0"
layer {
  name: "data"
  type: "AnnotatedData"
  top: "data"
  top: "label"
  include {
    phase: TRAIN
  }
  transform_param {
    mirror: true
    mean_value: 104.0
    mean_value: 117.0
    mean_value: 123.0
    resize_param {
      prob: 1.0
      resize_mode: WARP
      height: 480
      width: 480
      interp_mode: LINEAR
      interp_mode: AREA
      interp_mode: NEAREST
      interp_mode: CUBIC
      interp_mode: LANCZOS4
      height_scale: 480
      width_scale: 480
    }
    emit_constraint {
      emit_type: CENTER
    }
    distort_param {
      brightness_prob: 0.5
      brightness_delta: 32.0
      contrast_prob: 0.5
      contrast_lower: 0.5
      contrast_upper: 1.5
      hue_prob: 0.5
      hue_delta: 18.0
      saturation_prob: 0.5
      saturation_lower: 0.5
      saturation_upper: 1.5
      random_order_prob: 0.0
    }
    expand_param {
      prob: 0.5
      max_expand_ratio: 4.0
    }
  }
  data_param {
    source: "/home/coie/data/NumberPlate/lmdb/Nextan_trainval_lmdb"
    batch_size: 16
    backend: LMDB
  }
  annotated_data_param {
    batch_sampler {
      max_sample: 1
      max_trials: 1
    }
    batch_sampler {
      sampler {
        min_scale: 0.300000011921
        max_scale: 1.0
        min_aspect_ratio: 0.5
        max_aspect_ratio: 2.0
      }
      sample_constraint {
        min_jaccard_overlap: 0.10000000149
      }
      max_sample: 1
      max_trials: 50
    }
    batch_sampler {
      sampler {
        min_scale: 0.300000011921
        max_scale: 1.0
        min_aspect_ratio: 0.5
        max_aspect_ratio: 2.0
      }
      sample_constraint {
        min_jaccard_overlap: 0.300000011921
      }
      max_sample: 1
      max_trials: 50
    }
    batch_sampler {
      sampler {
        min_scale: 0.300000011921
        max_scale: 1.0
        min_aspect_ratio: 0.5
        max_aspect_ratio: 2.0
      }
      sample_constraint {
        min_jaccard_overlap: 0.5
      }
      max_sample: 1
      max_trials: 50
    }
    batch_sampler {
      sampler {
        min_scale: 0.300000011921
        max_scale: 1.0
        min_aspect_ratio: 0.5
        max_aspect_ratio: 2.0
      }
      sample_constraint {
        min_jaccard_overlap: 0.699999988079
      }
      max_sample: 1
      max_trials: 50
    }
    batch_sampler {
      sampler {
        min_scale: 0.300000011921
        max_scale: 1.0
        min_aspect_ratio: 0.5
        max_aspect_ratio: 2.0
      }
      sample_constraint {
        min_jaccard_overlap: 0.899999976158
      }
      max_sample: 1
      max_trials: 50
    }
    batch_sampler {
      sampler {
        min_scale: 0.300000011921
        max_scale: 1.0
        min_aspect_ratio: 0.5
        max_aspect_ratio: 2.0
      }
      sample_constraint {
        max_jaccard_overlap: 1.0
      }
      max_sample: 1
      max_trials: 50
    }
    label_map_file: "/home/coie/data/NumberPlate/labelmap_NumberPlate.prototxt"
  }
}
layer {
  name: "conv_1"
  type: "Convolution"
  bottom: "data"
  top: "conv_1"
  param {
    lr_mult: 0.0
    decay_mult: 0.0
  }
  param {
    lr_mult: 0.0
    decay_mult: 0.0
  }
  convolution_param {
    num_output: 8
    pad: 1
    kernel_size: 3
    weight_filler {
      type: "xavier"
    }
    bias_filler {
      type: "constant"
      value: 0.0
    }
  }
}
layer {
  name: "relu_1"
  type: "ReLU"
  bottom: "conv_1"
  top: "conv_1"
}
layer {
  name: "conv_1_1"
  type: "Convolution"
  bottom: "conv_1"
  top: "conv_1_1"
  param {
    lr_mult: 1.0
    decay_mult: 1.0
  }
  param {
    lr_mult: 2.0
    decay_mult: 0.0
  }
  convolution_param {
    num_output: 8
    pad: 1
    kernel_size: 3
    weight_filler {
      type: "xavier"
    }
    bias_filler {
      type: "constant"
      value: 0.0
    }
  }
}
layer {
  name: "relu_1_1"
  type: "ReLU"
  bottom: "conv_1_1"
  top: "conv_1_1"
}
layer {
  name: "pool_1"
  type: "Pooling"
  bottom: "conv_1_1"
  top: "pool_1"
  pooling_param {
    pool: MAX
    kernel_size: 2
    stride: 2
  }
}
layer {
  name: "conv_2"
  type: "Convolution"
  bottom: "pool_1"
  top: "conv_2"
  param {
    lr_mult: 0.0
    decay_mult: 0.0
  }
  param {
    lr_mult: 0.0
    decay_mult: 0.0
  }
  convolution_param {
    num_output: 8
    pad: 1
    kernel_size: 3
    weight_filler {
      type: "xavier"
    }
    bias_filler {
      type: "constant"
      value: 0.0
    }
  }
}
layer {
  name: "relu_2"
  type: "ReLU"
  bottom: "conv_2"
  top: "conv_2"
}
layer {
  name: "pool_2"
  type: "Pooling"
  bottom: "conv_2"
  top: "pool_2"
  pooling_param {
    pool: MAX
    kernel_size: 2
    stride: 2
  }
}
layer {
  name: "conv_3"
  type: "Convolution"
  bottom: "pool_2"
  top: "conv_3"
  param {
    lr_mult: 0.0
    decay_mult: 0.0
  }
  param {
    lr_mult: 0.0
    decay_mult: 0.0
  }
  convolution_param {
    num_output: 16
    pad: 1
    kernel_size: 3
    weight_filler {
      type: "xavier"
    }
    bias_filler {
      type: "constant"
      value: 0.0
    }
  }
}
layer {
  name: "relu_3"
  type: "ReLU"
  bottom: "conv_3"
  top: "conv_3"
}
layer {
  name: "pool_3"
  type: "Pooling"
  bottom: "conv_3"
  top: "pool_3"
  pooling_param {
    pool: MAX
    kernel_size: 2
    stride: 2
  }
}
layer {
  name: "conv_4"
  type: "Convolution"
  bottom: "pool_3"
  top: "conv_4"
  param {
    lr_mult: 0.0
    decay_mult: 0.0
  }
  param {
    lr_mult: 0.0
    decay_mult: 0.0
  }
  convolution_param {
    num_output: 16
    pad: 1
    kernel_size: 3
    weight_filler {
      type: "xavier"
    }
    bias_filler {
      type: "constant"
      value: 0.0
    }
  }
}
layer {
  name: "relu_4"
  type: "ReLU"
  bottom: "conv_4"
  top: "conv_4"
}
layer {
  name: "pool_4"
  type: "Pooling"
  bottom: "conv_4"
  top: "pool_4"
  pooling_param {
    pool: MAX
    kernel_size: 2
    stride: 2
  }
}
layer {
  name: "conv_5"
  type: "Convolution"
  bottom: "pool_4"
  top: "conv_5"
  param {
    lr_mult: 0.0
    decay_mult: 0.0
  }
  param {
    lr_mult: 0.0
    decay_mult: 0.0
  }
  convolution_param {
    num_output: 32
    pad: 1
    kernel_size: 3
    weight_filler {
      type: "xavier"
    }
    bias_filler {
      type: "constant"
      value: 0.0
    }
  }
}
layer {
  name: "relu_5"
  type: "ReLU"
  bottom: "conv_5"
  top: "conv_5"
}
layer {
  name: "pool_5"
  type: "Pooling"
  bottom: "conv_5"
  top: "pool_5"
  pooling_param {
    pool: MAX
    kernel_size: 2
    stride: 2
  }
}
layer {
  name: "conv_6"
  type: "Convolution"
  bottom: "pool_5"
  top: "conv_6"
  param {
    lr_mult: 0.0
    decay_mult: 0.0
  }
  param {
    lr_mult: 0.0
    decay_mult: 0.0
  }
  convolution_param {
    num_output: 32
    pad: 1
    kernel_size: 3
    weight_filler {
      type: "xavier"
    }
    bias_filler {
      type: "constant"
      value: 0.0
    }
  }
}
layer {
  name: "relu_6"
  type: "ReLU"
  bottom: "conv_6"
  top: "conv_6"
}
layer {
  name: "conv_6_norm"
  type: "Normalize"
  bottom: "conv_6"
  top: "conv_6_norm"
  norm_param {
    across_spatial: false
    scale_filler {
      type: "constant"
      value: 20.0
    }
    channel_shared: false
  }
}
layer {
  name: "conv_6_norm_mbox_loc"
  type: "Convolution"
  bottom: "conv_6_norm"
  top: "conv_6_norm_mbox_loc"
  param {
    lr_mult: 1.0
    decay_mult: 1.0
  }
  param {
    lr_mult: 2.0
    decay_mult: 0.0
  }
  convolution_param {
    num_output: 12
    pad: 1
    kernel_size: 3
    stride: 1
    weight_filler {
      type: "xavier"
    }
    bias_filler {
      type: "constant"
      value: 0.0
    }
  }
}
layer {
  name: "conv_6_norm_mbox_loc_perm"
  type: "Permute"
  bottom: "conv_6_norm_mbox_loc"
  top: "conv_6_norm_mbox_loc_perm"
  permute_param {
    order: 0
    order: 2
    order: 3
    order: 1
  }
}
layer {
  name: "conv_6_norm_mbox_loc_flat"
  type: "Flatten"
  bottom: "conv_6_norm_mbox_loc_perm"
  top: "conv_6_norm_mbox_loc_flat"
  flatten_param {
    axis: 1
  }
}
layer {
  name: "conv_6_norm_mbox_conf"
  type: "Convolution"
  bottom: "conv_6_norm"
  top: "conv_6_norm_mbox_conf"
  param {
    lr_mult: 1.0
    decay_mult: 1.0
  }
  param {
    lr_mult: 2.0
    decay_mult: 0.0
  }
  convolution_param {
    num_output: 6
    pad: 1
    kernel_size: 3
    stride: 1
    weight_filler {
      type: "xavier"
    }
    bias_filler {
      type: "constant"
      value: 0.0
    }
  }
}
layer {
  name: "conv_6_norm_mbox_conf_perm"
  type: "Permute"
  bottom: "conv_6_norm_mbox_conf"
  top: "conv_6_norm_mbox_conf_perm"
  permute_param {
    order: 0
    order: 2
    order: 3
    order: 1
  }
}
layer {
  name: "conv_6_norm_mbox_conf_flat"
  type: "Flatten"
  bottom: "conv_6_norm_mbox_conf_perm"
  top: "conv_6_norm_mbox_conf_flat"
  flatten_param {
    axis: 1
  }
}
layer {
  name: "conv_6_norm_mbox_priorbox"
  type: "PriorBox"
  bottom: "conv_6_norm"
  bottom: "data"
  top: "conv_6_norm_mbox_priorbox"
  prior_box_param {
    min_size: 25.6000003815
    max_size: 48.0
    aspect_ratio: 3.0
    flip: false
    clip: false
    variance: 0.10000000149
    variance: 0.10000000149
    variance: 0.20000000298
    variance: 0.20000000298
    img_size: 480
    step: 32.0
    offset: 0.5
  }
}
layer {
  name: "mbox_loc"
  type: "Concat"
  bottom: "conv_6_norm_mbox_loc_flat"
  top: "mbox_loc"
  concat_param {
    axis: 1
  }
}
layer {
  name: "mbox_conf"
  type: "Concat"
  bottom: "conv_6_norm_mbox_conf_flat"
  top: "mbox_conf"
  concat_param {
    axis: 1
  }
}
layer {
  name: "mbox_priorbox"
  type: "Concat"
  bottom: "conv_6_norm_mbox_priorbox"
  top: "mbox_priorbox"
  concat_param {
    axis: 2
  }
}
layer {
  name: "mbox_loss"
  type: "MultiBoxLoss"
  bottom: "mbox_loc"
  bottom: "mbox_conf"
  bottom: "mbox_priorbox"
  bottom: "label"
  top: "mbox_loss"
  include {
    phase: TRAIN
  }
  propagate_down: true
  propagate_down: true
  propagate_down: false
  propagate_down: false
  loss_param {
    normalization: VALID
  }
  multibox_loss_param {
    loc_loss_type: SMOOTH_L1
    conf_loss_type: SOFTMAX
    loc_weight: 1.0
    num_classes: 2
    share_location: true
    match_type: PER_PREDICTION
    overlap_threshold: 0.5
    use_prior_for_matching: true
    background_label_id: 1
    use_difficult_gt: true
    neg_pos_ratio: 3.0
    neg_overlap: 0.5
    code_type: CENTER_SIZE
    ignore_cross_boundary_bbox: false
    mining_type: MAX_NEGATIVE
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Caffe library has `param_need_backward, layer_need_backward_ and blob_need_backward_`.

`param_need_backward` controls weights update and if `lr_mult` is set 0, array element for that layer in the `param_need_backward` array has false. Then inside weight is not updated in Conv_layer.cpp since `param_propagate_down_` is false.

```
if (this->param_propagate_down_[0] || propagate_down[i]) {
      for (int n = 0; n < this->num_; ++n) {
        // gradient w.r.t. weight. Note that we will accumulate diffs.
        if (this->param_propagate_down_[0]) {
          this->weight_cpu_gemm(bottom_data + n * this->bottom_dim_,
              top_diff + n * this->top_dim_, weight_diff);
        }
        // gradient w.r.t. bottom data, if necessary.
        if (propagate_down[i]) {
          this->backward_cpu_gemm(top_diff + n * this->top_dim_, weight,
              bottom_diff + n * this->bottom_dim_);
        }
      }
    }
```

layer_need_backward_ and blob_need_backward_ are for layers and they are controlled in Net init according to Network architecture.